# Problema com emulador de marquina virtual Hyper v

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, emulador

O Hyper-v do meu computado esta ativa, e mesmo assim aparece o erro:

> O emulador não foi iniciado porque o hipervisor não esta em execução, provavelmente porque a virtualização assistida por hardware não esta habilitada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O drive está instalado?

Comment: Esta instalado. O Emulador do VS roda perfeitamente, mas este emulador do print que esta dando este problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por algum motivo o `hypervisor` foi desabilitado, para contornar execute o código abaixo (Habilitar) no `prompt de comando` como administrador e reinicie o computador. Para voltar a configuração original basta fazer o inverso.

Talvez o `virtualbox` seja o motivo pelo qual o `hypervisor` esteja desabilitado.

Habilitar

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

Desabilitar

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Answer (score 1):

Para poder iniciar máquinas virtuais, você precisa ativar a Virtualização no seu computador.

Para isso, abra a configuração da sua BIOS e procure por algo como "Virtualization" ou "VT-x" e ative.

Há vários tutoriais no YouTube ([exemplo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rL_iSFFFeAk)) que ajudam a ativar, procure um que seja melhor para você.

Já vi também muitas pessoas falando que antivírus (muita reclamação com o Avast) causava este problema também, mesmo com a virtualização ativada.

Espero que ajude, não pude comentar por causa da reputação. :)